# A better way to trim all elements in an object recursively?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, lodash

If I have an object like,

```
const obj = {
    field: {
        subfield: {
            innerObj: { a: ' asdasd  asdas . ' },
            innerArr: ['  s  ', '  ssad . '],
            innerArrObj: [ { b: '   adsad  ' } ],
        }
    }
}
```

I've come up with something like this,

```
const trimFields = (data) =>
  _.mapValues(data, (element, k) =>
    _.isArray(element)
      ? element.map((value) =>
          _.isObject(value) ? trimFields(value) : trimText(value)
        )
      : _.isObject(element)
      ? trimFields(element)
      : trimText(element)
  );
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better / more efficient way to do this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/750jwa4g/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd switch for array / object / other directly in the function, simplifying the recursive call:

```
 const trimFields = (data) =>
    _.isArray(data) 
      ? data.map(trimFields)
      :  _.isObject(data) 
        ? _.mapValues(trimFields)
        : trimText(data);
```

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're getting at, but this return an empty object. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ow2adp3x/).

Comment: Ah thought that `isObject` would exclude arrays, it doesnt ...

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, then I recalled that everything is technically an object in Javascript, as are arrays especially, as far as `_.isObject` is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a more general `deepMap` function and then call it with `trimText` and your object.  It then becomes easily reusable, and it separates out the handling of object navigation from your actual field transformation.  It's not hard to write, either with or without lodash.  Here's one version:

```js
const deepMap = (fn) => (obj) => 
  Array .isArray (obj) 
    ? obj .map (deepMap (fn))
  : Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => [k, deepMap (fn) (v)]))
  : // else 
    fn (obj)

const trimText = field => typeof field === 'string' ? field .trim () : field;

const obj = {field: {subfield: {innerObj: { a: ' asdasd  asdas . ' }, innerArr: ['  s  ', '  ssad . '], innerArrObj: [ { b: '   adsad  ' } ]}}}

console .log (
  deepMap (trimText) (obj)
)
```

Note that I simplified `trimText`, since `trim` is built into `String.prototype`.

Writing this generic version is pretty much no more difficult than a one-off version, and you can reuse it for other purposes.

```js
deepMap (square) ({a: 1, b: [2, 3, 4], c: [{d: 5}, {d: 6}]})
//=> {a: 1, b: [4, 9, 16], c: [{d: 25}, {d: 36}]}
```

Comment: `: typeof obj == "object" && obj` otherwise that will trow on `null`

Comment: @Kaiido: Yes, changed, although I like this version better: `Object(obj) === obj`.

Answer (score 0):

The lodash's [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#transform) function iterates both objects and arrays. You can create a recursive `mapValues()` function using `_.transform()`, and then apply a transformer function (`_.trim()` in this case) to handle all values:

```js
const recursiveMapValues = _.curry((fn, obj) => 
  _.transform(obj, (acc, value, key) => {
      acc[key] = _.isObject(value) ?
        recursiveMapValues(fn, value)
        :
        fn(value)
  }))
  
const trimFields = recursiveMapValues(v => _.isString(v) ? _.trim(v) : v)

const obj = {"field":{"subfield":{"innerObj":{"a":" asdasd  asdas . "},"innerArr":["  s  ","  ssad . ", 3],"innerArrObj":[{"b":"   adsad  "}]}}}

const result = trimFields(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```