# Usage of Promise.All in recursion doesn't seems to be working

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, async-await

Actual `doSomething` function posts `ele` to a remote API to do some calculations.

My calc function supposed to get the summation of the remote API's calculation for each element, It should run for every element without affecting how nested they are located.

However, Currently, I can't get this to work. How do I fix this?

```js
const doSomething = (ele) => new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(ele);
    resolve(ele * 2);//for example
})

const calc = (arr) => new Promise(
    async(resolve) => {
        console.log(arr.filter(ele => !Array.isArray(ele)));
        let sum = 0;
        const out = await Promise.all(arr.filter(ele => !Array.isArray(ele))
            .map(ele => doSomething(ele)));
        sum += out.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        const out2 = await Promise.all(arr.filter(ele => Array.isArray(ele))
            .map(ele => calc(ele)));
        sum += out2.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        resolve(sum);

    }
)

const process = async () => {
    console.log('processing..');
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6,7], 1, [8,[10,11]]];
    const out = await calc(arr);
    console.log(out);
}


process();
```

Comment: What you mean by "_I can't get this to work_"? What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: the fact that you are using async/await as the Promise constructor function suggests you don't know promises :p

Comment: `dosomething` !== `doSomething` - also, `out2` is an array, so `sum += out2` is going to mess you up

Comment: well, now you FIXED your code in the question, it's kind of embarrassing that my ANSWER addressed those issues - makes it look like I didn't read your code and inform you of the bugs in it

Comment: It didn't popup any error

Comment: Why is that error not caused?

Comment: Well, the code you've now rewritten WORKS - and the error was right there in the developer tools console `doSomething is not defined`

Comment: I wonder, why previous one didn't give me an error

Comment: it did, you just didn't look in the developer tools console did you

Comment: I was looking at the StackOverflow console print.  The actual error is with the +=out2 actually.

Comment: anyway returning promise was a bad practice I think

Comment: why you are creating a new prmoise in your function?

Comment: the console in stackoverlow does not show ALL errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While it may look like I've addressed issues that are non-existent - the original code in the question had ALL the flaws I address in this answer, including Second and Third below
>
> yes, the code in the question now works! But it clearly was flawed

First: no need for Promise constructor in calc function, since you use Promise.all which returns a promise, if you make calc async, just use await

Second: `dosomething` !== `doSomething`

Third: `out2` is an array, so `sum += out2` is going to mess you up

Fourth: `.map(ele => doSomething(ele))` can be written `.map(doSoemthing)` - and the same for the `calc(ele)` map

So, working code becomes:

```js
const doSomething = (ele) => new Promise(resolve => {
  resolve(ele * 2); //for example
})

const calc = async(arr) => {
  const out = await Promise.all(arr.filter(ele => !Array.isArray(ele)).map(doSomething));
  let sum = out.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  const out2 = await Promise.all(arr.filter(ele => Array.isArray(ele)).map(calc));
  sum += out2.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  return sum;
}

const process = async() => {
  console.log('processing..');
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6, 7], 1, [8, [10, 11]]];
  const out = await calc(arr);
  console.log(out);
}


process();
```

Comment: doSomething typo was not in original code, error was with the +=out2

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest a slightly different breakdown of the problem?

We can write one function that recursively applies your function to all (nested) elements of your array, and another to recursively total the results.

Then we `await` the result of the first call and pass it to the second.

I think these functions are simpler, and they are also reusable.

```js
const doSomething = async (ele) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(ele * 2), 1000);
})

const recursiveCall = async (proc, arr) => 
  Promise .all (arr .map (ele => 
    Array .isArray (ele) ? recursiveCall (proc, ele) : proc (ele)
  ))

const recursiveAdd = (ns) =>
  ns .reduce ((total, n) => total + (Array .isArray (n) ? recursiveAdd (n) : n), 0)

const process = async() => {
  console.log('processing..');
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6, 7], 1, [8, [10, 11]]];
  const processedArr = await recursiveCall (doSomething, arr);
  const out = recursiveAdd (processedArr)
  console.log(out);
}


process();
```

Comment: I adore the simplicity of this but I'm trying to see a way to generalise the `isArray(x) ? recur(x) : flat(x)` pattern...

Comment: `const nested = (flat, recur) => x => isArray(x) ? recur(x) : flat(x)` is interesting but not a perfect fit. maybe i'm over-thinking it, but I'm sensing a broader generalisation for both of our answers. Some sort of transducer for a nested input, but also flexible enough to lift into async context...

Answer (score 1):

I think a generic `deepReduce` solves this problem well. Notice it's written in synchronous form -

```js
const deepReduce = (f, init = null, xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce
    ( (r, x) =>
        Array.isArray(x)
          ? deepReduce(f, r, x)
          : f(r, x)
    , init
    )
```

Still, we can use `deepReduce` asynchronously by initialising with a promise and reducing with an `async` function -

```js
deepReduce
  ( async (r, x) =>
      await r + await doSomething(x)
  , Promise.resolve(0)
  , input
  )
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

See the code in action here -

```js
const deepReduce = (f, init = null, xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce
    ( (r, x) =>
        Array.isArray(x)
          ? deepReduce(f, r, x)
          : f(r, x)
    , init
    )

const doSomething = x =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200, x * 2))

const input =
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6,7], 1, [8,[10,11]]]

deepReduce
  ( async (r, x) =>
      await r + await doSomething(x)
  , Promise.resolve(0)
  , input
  )
  .then(console.log, console.error)

// 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + (10 + 14) + 2 + (16 + (20 + 22))
// => 116

console.log("doing something. please wait...")
```

---

**further generalisation**

Above we are hand-encoding a summing function, (`+`), with the empty sum `0`. In reality, this function could be more complex and maybe we want a more general pattern so we can construct our program piecewise. Below we take synchronous `add` and convert it to an asynchronous function using `liftAsync2(add)` -

```js
const add = (x = 0, y = 0) =>
  x + y  // <-- synchronous

const main =
  pipe
    ( deepMap(doSomething) // <-- first do something for every item
    , deepReduce(liftAsync2(add), Promise.resolve(0)) // <-- then reduce
    )

main([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6,7], 1, [8,[10,11]]])
  .then(console.log, console.error)

// 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + (10 + 14) + 2 + (16 + (20 + 22))
// => 116
```

`deepMap` and `deepReduce` generics. These are in curried form so they can plug directly into `pipe`, but that is only a matter of style -

```js
const deepReduce = (f = identity, init = null) => (xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce
    ( (r, x) =>
        Array.isArray(x)
          ? deepReduce(f, r)(x)
          : f(r, x)
    , init
    )

const deepMap = (f = identity) => (xs = []) =>
  xs.map
    ( x =>
        Array.isArray(x)
          ? deepMap(f)(x)
          : f(x)
    )
```

`liftAsync2` takes a common binary (has two parameters) function and "lifts" it into the asynchronous context. `pipe` and `identity` are commonly available in most functional libs or easy to write yourself  -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const pipe = (...fs) =>
  x => fs.reduce((r, f) => f(r), x)

const liftAsync2 = f =>
  async (x, y) => f (await x, await y)
```

Here's all of the code in a demo you can run yourself. Notice because `deepMap` synchronously applies `doSomething` to all nested elements, all promises are run in parallel. This is in direct contrast to the serial behaviour in the first program. This may or may not be desirable so it's important to understand the difference in how these run  -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const pipe = (...fs) =>
  x => fs.reduce((r, f) => f(r), x)
    
const liftAsync2 = f =>
  async (x, y) => f (await x, await y)

const deepReduce = (f = identity, init = null) => (xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce
    ( (r, x) =>
        Array.isArray(x)
          ? deepReduce(f, r)(x)
          : f(r, x)
    , init
    )

const deepMap = (f = identity) => (xs = []) =>
  xs.map
    ( x =>
        Array.isArray(x)
          ? deepMap(f)(x)
          : f(x)
    )
    
const doSomething = x =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200, x * 2))

const add =
  (x, y) => x + y

const main =
  pipe
    ( deepMap(doSomething)
    , deepReduce(liftAsync2(add), Promise.resolve(0))
    )

main([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6,7], 1, [8,[10,11]]])
  .then(console.log, console.error)

// 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + (10 + 14) + 2 + (16 + (20 + 22))
// => 116

console.log("doing something. please wait...")
```

Comment: Nice.  I've used `Promise`s in a reduce with `.then`, but never thought to use `await` that way.  But there is one real downside compared to the other answers here.  This technique works well when you need to resolve Promises sequentially.  But for this problem the calls are independent and could run in parallel.

Comment: Scott, dangit I was 9 minutes too slow with my edit! I wanted to expand on this last night but I needed some sleep and had to keep it short zzz

Comment: Sorry.  I'll make sure to wait an extra ten minutes next time!

Comment: Hahaha I think maybe it's time to get out for some fresh air!

Comment: Note the generalization of your `deepMap` in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61101523).  That could do with a refactoring to use an `objectMap` (or a polymorphic `map`) function, but it's one possible generalization of this version..